# String not converted to integer

Tags: ruby, string, integer

I want to convert the price of an item expressed as a string into a numeral. Here is my code:

```
puts price # => £0.75
price.gsub!(/[£]/,'')
puts price # => 0.75
"#{price}".to_i
puts price # => 0.75
price < 1 # => comparison of String with 1 failed (ArgumentError)
```

Is it something to do with the definition of the `price` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `"#{price}".to_i` is not doing anything meaningful. It is just leaving an integer in that position in the code, and is not used. If you do `price = price.to_i`, then it will probably work.

As a general tip, when you want to look into what is happening, use `p` rather than `puts`. Your using `puts` made it difficult for you to tell that `price` is still a string right before the comparison. If you had used `p`, then you would have been able to distinguish a string and numeral.

Comment: Does this change the price variable from there onwards or would doing that require adding a ! to it?

Comment: From that point, it becomes the numeral `0`. If you want access to the original string after it, use a different variable name for the numeral.

Comment: If what you mean by "adding !" is the expectation for there being a side effect to the object/variable, that is impossible. `gsub!` worked because the input and output are both strings, and their identity can be retained while modifying the content. But between a string and a numeral, there is no way to retain the identity. Hence, you need to reassign the variable.

Comment: I realise now my initial question was not what I actually wanted. I have a string £0.75 and I want to take from it the number "0.75" to compare with other numbers later on. I was told I need to use 'to_f' to turn it into a float? I want to compare it with integers though, will this be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is:

```
price = '£0.75'
price.gsub!(/[£]/,'') # => "0.75"
```

`/[£]/` is an awkward way to use the regex since you're creating a set of a single character which could be more easily written as:

```
price.gsub!(/£/,'') # => "0.75"
```

But, using `gsub` or `gsub!` isn't as fast as either of these:

```
price.tr('£','')      # => "0.75"
price.delete('£')     # => "0.75"
```